# Right way to print Document without saving it

Tags: java, pdf, methods, printing, document

I've been trying to print my pdf file I created inside the program but I couldn't.

```
document.open();
PDF.addTitlePage(document, "Planning des examens " + niveau.getValue());
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(new float[]{70, 100, 100, 100, 100, 50});
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
```

I don't know how to attach document into job.

Comment: Which program "inside the program"?

Comment: I meant inside the application without saving it to disque

Comment: Do you mean within Java? - I don't know Java very well.
(Show) where you declare/initialize `PDF` and `document`.
Logically:
create a document,
fill it with data,
create a printJob from document or create a printJob and assign the document to it,
send printJob to printer.
Also, if I open something, I should close it.
I hope this is more helpful than confusing...